# TProcess - Catching output from several Process.Input.Write(...) commands

Tags: c++, pascal, freepascal, lazarus, chess

I want chess engine to analyze some game in pgn format.

Till now I have.

```
begin
// ...
P:=TProcess.Create(nil);
stL:=TStringList.create;
P.Commandline:='Houdini'; // <- this is chess engine, Houdini.exe
P.Options:=P.Options+[poUsePipes];
P.ShowWindow:=swoHide;
P.Execute;

st:='uci'+ Lineending;
P.Input.Write(st[1], Length(st));
// st:=P.Output.ReadAnsiString;    <- this is my try
// showmessage(st);
st:='setoption name multipv value 3'+lineending;
P.Input.Write(st[1], Length(st)); // so after second command how to catch different output
st:='isready'+lineending;
P.Input.Write(st[1], Length(st));
st:='ucinewgame'+lineending;
P.Input.Write(st[1], Length(st));
st:='isready'+lineending;
P.Input.Write(st[1], Length(st));

// another part of code should be here ***

st:='quit'+lineending;
P.Input.Write(st[1], Length(st)); // quiting the engine
stL.LoadFromStream(P.Output);
stL.SaveToFile('AjDaVidime.txt');  // nothing stores particular

P.Free;
stL.Free; 
end;
```

So question is how to get output from engine output after every P.Input.Write...

Another part of code follows (this is for strange  stackoverflow behaviour to post my question.
This code should be in first one in ***

```
// This for loop is main loop for analyzing chess game
for i:=1 to moves do begin
 st:='position fen '+arrayFen[i]+lineending;
 P.Input.Write(st[1], Length(st));
 st:='go movetime 1000'+lineending;  // Fen is position 1000ms is 1sec, so engine Must analyze 1 sec. that position, so go movetime 1000 is command.
 P.Input.Write(st[1], Length(st));
 Sleep(1000); // <- is this neccessary?
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Afaik it is not possible to wait for output with TProcess in a cross platform way. A read on the pipe might block till the specified bytes are received.

Probably it is possible to workaround this by using (baseunix.fp)select or (windows.)waitforsingleobject on the handle of the stream (which is the OS handle).

I don't know any code that does this, but I think the debugger code in Lazarus is the most complex TProcess using code (calling GDB), so I suggest to look into that.